# validating file name matches directory name

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, terraform

Have to write a ruby script which can validate that the key in s3 matches directory name.
I have a json file, path name- `Apple/Employee/Background/test.tf`

How can I validate that my directory path `Apple/Employee/Background/` matches with the "key": "*Apple/Employee/Background/*" in json file.

I used jq and parsed json file to retrive the value of "key".

```
cat conf.json | jq '.terraform[] | .backend[] | .s3[] | .key'
```

"*Apple/Employee/Background/terraform.tfstate*"

I want to compare only `Apple/Employee/Background` with directory path and see if they are same or not.

json file looks like:

```
"terraform": [
    {
  "backend": [
    {
      "s3": [
        {
          "bucket": "terraform-dev",
          "dynamodb": "terraform_files",
          "encrypt": "true",
          "key": "Apple/Employee/Background/terraform.tfstate"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "required_version": "~> 0.11.8"
}
]
```

the directory path looks like- Apple/Employee/Background/conf.tf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.dirname` to get the directory path minus the base entry (in this case, 'terraform.tfstate')

```rb
# Assuming `key` contains the value from the JSON file
dir = File.dirname(key) # => "Apple/Employee/Background"
```

Note that the path is returned without a trailing slash.